# Managing disk space and finding large consumers of disk space

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, disk-usage, ubuntu-mate

Ok so running the command in Ubuntu Mate 18.04

> $df -h

returns the following

```
udev             32G    0    32G    0%    /dev 
tmpfs           6.3G    2.4M    6.3G    1%    /run 
/dev/sdc2        40G    36G    1.4G    97%    / 
tmpfs            32G    187M    32G    1%    /dev/shm 
tmpfs           5.0M    4.0K    5.0M    1%    /run/lock 
tmpfs            32G    0    32G    0%    /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdc1       549M    5.8M    544M    2%    /boot/efi 
/dev/sdc3       630G    94G    505G    16%    /home 
tmpfs           6.3G    56K    6.3G    1%    /run/user/1000
```

How do I determine which files are taking up the most space on /sdc2?

Comment: done Ubuntu Mate 18.04

Answer (score 3):

For a command line answer, `du -a -h --all | sort -h` will show files, in the current directory and its subdirectories.  Perform that after moving to the root of /sdc2 .

As an alternative, install [ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/man) then run
`sudo apt install ncdu`

and then run it, also from the root of /sdc2, to see which directories are consuming the most space, then go to that directory and run ls -h to find the files in question.

You can also use `find -type f -exec du -Sh {} + | sort -rh | head -n 10` to find your 10 largest files; again, start in the root of /sdc2 .